# Generate a list of unique combinations from a list

Tags: haskell, combinations

I want to generate a list of all unique ways to choose two from a list of numbers in Haskell. So from the list `[1,2,3]` I would like `[[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]]`. Order is not important so I want to avoid producing both `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` for example.

My current solution is:

```
pairs :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
pairs x = nub $ map sort $ map (take 2) (permutations x)
```

This isn't a particularly nice solution however and it certainly has some serious performance issues. Is there a simple and efficient solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pairs xs = [[x1, x2] | (x1:xs1) <- tails xs, x2 <- xs1]
```

...assuming the list starts out unique, or you could compose this with `nub` otherwise.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That's just the thing I was after.